# What is the correct structure to set the source model for magento attribute

Tags: magento, model, attributes

I'm trying to add an attribute to my magento products that relies on custom functionality to provide the options for this attribute.

For this I have created a source model in MyNamespace/MyExtension/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/MyAttribute

Then I tried telling Magento to use my model by setting the source_model for this attribute, when I kept getting the following error:

```
Source model "mynamespace/myextension_product_attribute_source_myattribute" not found for attribute "vendor"
```

I believe I tried all possible combinations, like:

```
myextension/product_attribute_source_myattribute
mynamespace_myextension/product_attribute_source_myattribute
mynamespace/myextension_model_product_attribute_source_myattribute
```

and so on, without any luck. Then I used the classname:

```
MyNamespace_MyExtension_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_MyAttribute
```

which to my surprise actually works. However, I would still like to know what structure using the magento convention is the way to go - i.e., magento uses:

```
catalog/product_attribute_source_countryofmanufacture
```

to load Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Countryofmanufacture class

Answer (score 0):

After some struggling with the implementation of other modules and their configuration I finally found the answer.

The modules configuration file defines the base namespace for models, under which multiple model classes can be loaded:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <mynamespace_myextension>
            <class>MyNamespace_MyExtension_Model</class>
        </mynamespace_myextension>
    </models>
</global>
```

Now, when loading a module, you state the xml definition you use as namespace before the slash, then omit namespaces already given in the class tag and add the specific structure for the model:

```
mynamespace_myextension/product_attribute_source_myattribute
```

You can load additional models under the same namespace without having to add them specifically to your xml